# Input text value not changing in jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, dialog

I am trying to change the value of an input text box that is inside a dialog based on a value selected by user in a select option in the previous form submitted by the user. I am able to get the value and I able to set the value to the text box inside the dialog at first. But when I re-submit the form with a different option selected and open the dialog again, the value doesn't get changed at first. It changes only when I open the dialog a second time.

Below is the code where the dialog is called and function that sets the value to the text box is called:

```
$("#displayOrderDetailsDiv").on('click','.shippedOrder',function() {
    var dc = $("#DC").val();
    var shipmentKey = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').text().trim();
    $("#printLabelDialog").html("<form><fieldset><label for=\"ip\">Printer IP</label> <input type=\"text\" name=\"ip\" id=\"ipAddr\" class=\"text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all\" placeholder=\"IP address of printer(eg: 10.56.89.175)\"> <labelfor=\"stnid\">Station ID:</label> <input type=\"text\" name=\"stnid\" id=\"stnid\" class=\"text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all\" placeholder=\"station id in 3 digits(Eg: 002)\"></fieldset></form>");
    setIPandStn(dc);
    $( "#printLabelDialog" ).dialog( {
        autoOpen: false,
        height : 200,
        width : 900,
        modal: true,
        buttons: [ { 
            text: "Print", 
            click: function() {
                var ip = $("#ipAddr").val().trim();
                if (!validateIp(ip)){
                    alert("Please enter a valid IP");
                    return false;
                }
                var stnid = $("#stnid").val().trim();
                if ((stnid.length != 3) || (isNaN(stnid))){
                    alert("Please enter a valid station Id");
                    return false;
                }
                var ajax_load = "<img class='loading' src='loading.gif' alt='loading...' style='width: 35px; height: 35px; top: 50%; left: 50%; position:absolute;' />";
                $( this ).html(ajax_load);
                var options = {
                    buttons: {}
                };
                $("#printLabelDialog").dialog('option', options);
                $( "#printLabelDialog" ).dialog( "option", "width", 150 );
                $( "#printLabelDialog" ).dialog( "option", "height", 120 );
                $.ajax({
                    url : 'printLabelTrackingNumber.jsp',
                    type : 'POST',
                    data : {
                        ipAddr : ip,
                        stationId : stnid,
                        sKey : shipmentKey
                    },
                    success : function(data) {

                        $( "#printLabelDialog" ).dialog( "option", "width", 400 );

                        $("#printLabelDialog").dialog('option', options);
                        $("#printLabelDialog").html(data);
                    },
                    error : function(err) {
                        alert(err.responseText);
                    },
                    close : function(e,ui){
                        $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
                    }
                }); 
            } 
        } ]


    });


    $( "#printLabelDialog" ).dialog( "open" );

});
```

Below is the function to set the value to the dialog

```
function setIPandStn(dcVal){
    if (dcVal == "02"){
        $("#ipAddr").val("10.56.89.175");
        $("#stnid").val("102");
    }
    else if (dcVal == "13"){
        $("#ipAddr").val("10.56.111.48");
        $("#stnid").val("101");
    }
    else if (dcVal == "12"){
        $("#ipAddr").val("10.26.25.166");
        $("#stnid").val("004");
    }
}
```

As you see, I am trying to set the value of `$("#ipAddr")` with the function `setIPandStn()`. The `dc` value is changed when I submit the form, but the value inside the text box gets changed only if I open and close the dialog once and open it the second time.

Could someone please help me identify the problem?

Comment: I tried and I get the correct value. The dialog does not get changed the first time I click on it no matter what is present in the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, it looks like you submit the form via Ajax and then open up a new dialog box in the success function. However, you don't run the "setIPandStn(dc);" function again until you click on the dialog trigger again.

I suggest running setIPandStn(dc); again in the success function of your ajax call, after you opened the new dialog box.

```
[...]
success : function(data) { 
  $( "#printLabelDialog" ).dialog( "option", "width", 400 );  
  $("#printLabelDialog").dialog('option', options);
  $("#printLabelDialog").html(data);
  setIPandStn(dc);
},
[...]
```

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, but that ajax call I am performing is not where I am setting the value of dc. That is in a different form.